# Need to insert data using merge query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `function role` with 2 columns `role` and `function`. Both are primary keys.

Data is as follows

```
role         function

analyst      execute
BAU          execute
SYS          execute
SYS          create
```

I want all roles with `execute` function to have even `create` function also.

How to achieve this through sql query?

My output should be like

```
role           function

analyst      execute
analyst      create
BAU          execute
BAU          create
SYS          execute
SYS          create
```

Please help!

Comment: Which dbms? (The answer may depend on the dbms product used...)

Comment: Are there any other possible function values than execute and create?

Comment: oracle .. these 3 roles are mapped to many functions.. i want even create also as a function mapped to the role.. but with a merge query

Answer (score 0):

> Both are primary keys.

It is not possible. A table can have atmost one primary key.(*A combination of column is, however, possible*)

Even if you have one of it as the primary key then also you cannot insert duplicate values in your table.

And lastly try to avoid making primary keys on columns having datatype as varchar or text.

Also you can use the simple insert statement to insert the data in your table like this:

```
insert into myTable(`role`,`function`)
values('analyst','execute')
```

Note that role and function are reserved keywords for some database. So you need to beware of it and use the correct syntax to overcome it. Like backticks for Mysql.[] in SQL Server.

Comment: I suppose OP means they together are the primary key.

Comment: @jarlh:- A contradiction in my understanding ;)

Comment: @jarlh:- Updated my answer to overcome it!

Comment: And most other dbms products do it the ANSI SQL way and use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. "function".

Comment: database is oracle .. these 3 roles are mapped to many functions.. i want even create also as a function mapped to the role.. but with a merge query.

Comment: [my requirement is to insert a subset of that table with only function name changed]

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL compliant answer, should work well with Oracle too:

```
insert into function_role
    select role, 'create' from function_role f1
    where "function" = 'execute'
      and not exists (select 1 from function_role f2
                      where f2.role = r1.role
                        and f2."function" = 'create')
```

Since `function` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL it's delimited as `"function"`.